# How to get only Saturday dates between two given dates in iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am trying to fetch only dates that are on Saturdays between two given dates.

How can I do this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no direct way to loop between two dates and you can't get the weekday directly from a NSDate object. So you need to add just a few more lines to make it work. The key here is to use NSDateComponents. For this example, I'm using the Gregorian calendar. By default, according to Apple's documentation, weekdays start on Sunday, which is day one (literally 1). Please, don't consider that Sunday is zero (it's common to get confused).

Knowing that, saturday is the seventh day in the week, so we can say it is the integer 7. Here is the code. From this, you can easily create a method to add to your class/category and pass the weekday you want to check as a parameter.

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger saturday = 7;

// Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

// Using a Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *currentDate = fromDate;

// Iterate from fromDate until toDate
while ([currentDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

    if (dateComponents.weekday == saturday) {
        count++;
    }

    // "Increment" currentDate by one day.
    currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
                                            toDate:currentDate
                                           options:0];
}

NSLog(@"count = %d", count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```
-(NSArray*)specificdaysInCalendar:(NSArray*)holidays   {
    //if you want saturdays, thn you have to pass 7 in the holidays array
    NSDate *startdate = START_DATE;
    NSDate *endDate = END_DATE;
    NSDateComponents *dayDifference = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    NSUInteger dayOffset = 1;
    NSDate *nextDate = startdate;
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;

    do {
        NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:nextDate];
        int weekday = [comps weekday];
        //NSLog(@"%i,%@",weekday,nextDate);
        if ([holidays containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",weekday]]) {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";

            NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
            NSDate *outDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            //NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",nextDate,dateString,outDate);
            [dates addObject:outDate];
        }


        [dayDifference setDay:dayOffset++];
        NSDate *d = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dayDifference toDate:startdate options:0];

        nextDate = d;
    } while([nextDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending);

    return dates;

}
```

Just pass the number 7 for saturday in the argument array